# PHP Variable changes its own value on equal loops

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a variable putting out the coordinates of a address. I am printing the coordinates before the name to test at the moment. On odd number loops (it is in a foreach loop) it works fine, putting the variable in the `data-latLng` attribute. While on Even number loops it gives out different values - not coordinates. values like: `2` and `.`.

Here is what I mean:

An odd numbered loop would print this out:

[image: odd]

Meanwhile on an even loop number, the `data-latLng` attribute puts out different values:

[image: even]

[image: even]

Here is the code:

```
$area_lat_long = isset($area_lat_long[$mapCounter])?$area_lat_long[$mapCounter]:"-26.2041028, 28.047305100000017";
echo $area_lat_long;
echo '<strong>area: '. $streetAdd[$count] .'         <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mapModal" data-latLng="'. $area_lat_long .'" style="cursor:pointer;"></a><br>';
$mapCounter++;
```

The PHP code runs above the table code, the code above gives the line of the coordinates and then the area.

As you can see, the `$area_lat_long` gives coordinates before every area, but when using the EXACT same variable for the `data-latLng` it changes on even loops?

**Edit**
To the guys who wanted the whole loop in the comments:

```
foreach ($streetAdd as $key){
                print_r($area_lat_long);
                //LAT LONG
                $area_lat_long = isset($area_lat_long[$count])?$area_lat_long[$count]:"-26.2041028, 28.047305100000017";
                echo $area_lat_long;
                echo '<strong>area: '. $streetAdd[$count] .'         <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mapModal" data-latLng="'. $area_lat_long .'" style="cursor:pointer;"></a><br>';
                $mapCounter++;?>
                <input type="hidden" id="street_address" name="street_address[<?php echo $count; ?>]" value="<?php echo $streetAdd[$count];?>">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Media Type</th>
                        <th>Quantity Required</th>
                        <th>Average Asset Price</th>
                        <th><!-- Remaining Total --></th>
                        <th>More Options</th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="assetCounter">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php

                    $j           = 0;
                    $total_used  = 0;
                    $total_bal   = isset($budget)?$budget:0;
                    $qty         = 1;
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($my_categories as $key) { //loop thru chosen media types
                        foreach ((array)$key as $data) {
//                                print_r($data);
                            //check valid description
                            $j++;
                            $data_description = isset($data->mec_description)?$data->mec_description:'';

                            $latitude_longitude = explode(",",$area_lat_long); //print_r($latitude_longitude);
                            $latitude = $latitude_longitude[0];
                            $longitude = isset($latitude_longitude[1])?$latitude_longitude[1]:$latitude;
                            //pricing
                            $min_price = isset($data->asg_min_price)?$data->asg_min_price:0;
                            $max_price = isset($data->asg_max_price)?$data->asg_max_price:0;
                            $average_p = ($min_price + $max_price)/2;

                            $total_used += $average_p;
                            $total_bal  -= $average_p;

                            if($total_bal < 0){
                                $total_bal = 0;
                            }

                            if($average_p == 0){
                                $title = "Pricing information not yet available from Media Owners";
                            } else {
                                $title = "NOTE: These are just estimates/guidelines, latest pricing information will be received from Media Owners quotations";
                            }

                            ?>
                            <tr class="asset_<? echo $counterForAsset; ?>">
                                <td><?php
                                    echo strtoupper($mec_stuff[$i]);
                                    ?>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="media_category" name="mec_id[]" value="<?php
                                        foreach($mec_stuff as $ms) {
                                            echo $ms . ',';
                                        }
                                    ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="media_category" name="media_category[]" value="<?php echo $data_description; ?>"></input></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control q_asset_<? echo $counterForAsset; ?> med_quantity" name="med_quantity[]" id="med_quantity" placeholder="Quantity Required" value="1"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" readonly="true" name="avg_total[]" id="asset_<? echo $counterForAsset; ?>" class="form-control avg_asset_<? echo $counterForAsset; ?>" value="<?php echo number_format($total_bal,2); ?>" title="<?php echo $title;?>"/></td>
<!--                                    <td><input type="text" readonly="true" name="avg_total[]" id="avg_total--><?php //echo $j; ?><!--" class="form-control asset_--><?// echo $i; ?><!--" value="--><?php //echo number_format($total_bal,2); ?><!--" title="--><?php //echo $title;?><!--"/></td>-->
                                    <td><input type="text" readonly="true" name="rem_total[]" id="asset_<? echo $counterForAsset; ?>" class="form-control rem_asset_<? echo $counterForAsset; ?>"  value="<?php echo number_format($total_bal,2); ?>"/></td>
<!--                                    <td><input type="text" readonly="true" name="rem_total[]" id="rem_total--><?php //echo $j; ?><!--" class="form-control --><?// echo $i; ?><!-- asset_--><?// echo $i; ?><!--"  value="--><?php //echo number_format($total_bal,2); ?><!--"/></td>-->
                                    <td><?php echo "<a class='js-fire-modal btn btn-info' type='button' data-toggle='modal' data-mecid='$mec_stuff[$i]' href='#' name='size_button'  onclick=\"sizeModal2(1, $j, '$latitude','$longitude','$description')\">>>></a>";?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td colspan="4" id="<?php echo $j; ?>"></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php $i ++; $counterForAsset++; }


                    }?>
                    <tr>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> <input type="hidden" id="hidSubtotal<?php echo $j;?>" value="<?php echo number_format($total_used,2); ?>"></td>
                        <td> Subtotal</td>
                        <td> <span id="lblSubtotal<?php echo $j; ?>"><?php echo number_format($total_used,2); ?></span> </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <?php $count++;
            }
```

Comment: `"but when using the EXACT same variable...it changes on even loops?"` Exact same variable but with different value. You posted lots of pictures but not even the full loop, so I don't know what you expect anyone to say.

Comment: Please post more code. We need context. Include the foreach loop and some code around it, at LEAST. Ideally we have the entire tidbit of code that relates to what is happening.

Comment: @teh1 I have included the loop for you

Comment: @developerwjk As you can see, yes the value of the variable changes on each loop, but when if it is an even loop, between using it before the name of the area and putting it into the `data-latLng` attribute it changes?

Comment: Put spaces before and after *binary* operators. You've got ternary operators with `?` and `:` connected to the variable names. I don't think that will work well.  Then you have *unary* operators with spaces that shouldn't be there, i.e. `$i ++;` which should be `$i++;`

Comment: @developerwjk tried that, no success

Comment: first you should fix mismatch: $streetAdd as $key ... $my_categories as $key

Comment: That's not the whole problem, just what jumps out at me most.

Comment: @Electronick Good eye, this is not all my code, I am implementing the map section. And I am running into this problem of the variables not changing correctly

Comment: '. $area_lat_long .' try add '. ((string)$area_lat_long) .' or mb change whole string to sprintf('<strong>area: %s         <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mapModal" data-latLng="%s" style="cursor:pointer;"></a><br>', $streetAdd[$count], $area_lat_long);

Comment: is it normal, that you using same name for left and right sides?
$area_lat_long = isset($area_lat_long[$count]) ?$area_lat_long[$count]:"-26.2041028, 28.047305100000017";

Comment: @Electronick No, I would not normally do that, but as I said, it is not all my code. I am only implementing the map section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($a as $b) {
    $x = isset($x[$c]) ? $x[$c] : "foo7";
    echo $x;
}
```

Let us "run" that piece of code, assuming
    $x = array('c' => 'lat,lng');
before the loop.

So loop #1 prints 'lat,lng'.

Loop #2 checks if `isset('lat,lng'[$c])`, evaluates to `false`, so `$x` will be `'foo'`.

'foo' will be printed.

Loop #3 does the same as #2, but checks if `isset('foo'[$c])`, again evaluating to `false`.

Again 'foo' will be printed.

That's the reason.

I don't know what else you are doing outside that loop and most of the code seems to do nothing or nothing *intended* really.